# Is "molten" the past participle of "melt"?

Tags: past-participles

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/molten) tells me that *melt* is a regular verb, and *molten* is simply an adjective. But in the irregular verb appendix of the *Shanghai High School English Exam Vocabulary* word book, *molten* is the past participle of *melt*, which leads me into confusion.

[image: Infinitive: melt. Past Tense: melted. Past Participle: melted, molten]

How would you explain this? Are there differences between *molten* and *melted*?

Comment: What 'word book'? Title and author, please. Is it online? Can you give a link?

Comment: What is a word book??

Comment: A word book is of course a dictionary-glossary-lexicon thingy.  (German for "dictionary" is _Wörterbuch_, literally "words book".)

Comment: [Here's the Wiktionary discussion of this suffix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-en#Etymology_1).  Note that English has other _-en_ suffixes that are unrelated to this one, such as the ones in "children" or "redden".

Comment: I'll make it clearer. The work book, which I mentioned here, refered to the high school Shanghai High School English Exam Vocabulary Handbook. This handbook lists all the vocabulary that is likely to be examined in the College Entrance Examination (sort of GCSE) and it has a list of irregular verbs. (Sadly, I havn't got an online edition) According to the nice answers below, I 've already learned that *molten* is improper to appear at the 'past participle' column of 'melt', or at least in some way out-of-date. Already e-mailed the editor of the handbook.

Comment: A typo -- word book.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

'Molten' is **not** the past participle of 'melt' in modern English, although that may be the etymology of the word. It now describes a *state* of matter, namely that it has been heated to very high temperatures to turn a solid into liquid state.

It is only really noteworthy when a substance is not in its usual state. For example, people *tend* to expect nitrogen to be a gas, so when it is in liquid state we nearly always refer to it as 'liquid nitrogen'. Likewise, 'molten metal' or 'molten rock' are noteworthy because they are normally solid.

This is somewhat in contrast with the way 'melted' is used. When you note that something has melted, it is usually because it was solid when frozen or refrigerated, but subsequently thawed into a liquid in warmer temperatures. 'Molten' is more likely to refer to something that remains a solid even in warm temperatures and must be deliberately subjected to very intense heat to change its state of matter to a liquid. Nobody would ever say 'molten ice' - they would say it had melted. In cooking, we do refer to butter melted in a pan as 'melted butter' but this isn't really an exception - it doesn't require extreme temperatures to cause butter to melt; in fact it can often melt itself at some room temperatures.

Comment: *Molten' is not the past tense of 'melt'* That's true only in current English. **molten** *is* indeed the archaic form of the past participle of *melt*. Someone reading some non-contemporary literary work could well find that *molten* is used as a participle.

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine agreed. I didn't really think archaic english was needed, as the OP was asking about usage, not etymology. However, I've added a note about that into my answer now.

Comment: @Astralbee Just being a noodge here, but "superheated" in your answer should be just "heated." (This is ELL after all, and words matter ; ). A superheated solid has been raised above its melting point but prevented from melting by some means. If a solid is heated and it melts at its melting point, it was not superheated at all, it was just heated.

Comment: @mta Actually prevented from boiling, not melting necessarily. You can superheat water. But yes, it was the wrong terminology and I've amended.

Comment: "Melted plastic" or "molten plastic"? I would say, 1) melted can be used for everything, 2) molten can only be used for some things, 3) for some specific things, molten is preferred to melted, but this is verging on archaic since we now know that the process of, e.g., stone melting is the same as the process of ice melting, just at higher temperature.

Comment: @user3067860: Interesting point: "molten plastic" implies still liquid (and still hot, with connotations of dangerous).  "Melted plastic" could I think be used correctly to talk about plastic that had melted in the past, but had since cooled and re-hardened into a mis-shaped form.  Like a candle with dribbles of wax, or more dramatic.  e.g. "The melted plastic toy soldier had a creepy deformed appearance".

Comment: @PeterCordes I think around here many people would tend to use melted as an adjective for currently liquid plastic as well. "Don't touch melted plastic, you will burn yourself." Even "melted rock" would probably be OK, although more people would use molten.

Comment: @user3067860: Yes, melted can also be used to talk about still-liquid substances.  I didn't mean to imply otherwise.  When I commented earlier, I thought that was the distinction you were making, but in hindsight I see you were talking about "melted ice" (fine and only a bit unusual) vs. "molten ice / molten water" (nonsense).

Comment: "Holpen" was once the past participle of "help."  I do think that _molten_ is more about the state and _melted_ carries a bit more of a sense of how it got that way.  For example, if I saw a crucible of glowing liquid iron, I'd surely call it "molten iron," but if I were describing a process, I might use either word: _heat the crucible containing the scrap iron until it the contents become liquid, then pour the melted iron..." or "...then pour the molten iron..."

Comment: @phoog Of course, there are a few examples of this grammar that we still use today, such as 'gotten'. Sometimes the question calls for a lesson in early English but I don't think this one does.

Comment: I've only seen molten used to refer to 1.] metals (with the notable exception of Mercury, which is normally liquid at room temperature.  And maybe Gallium which can melt in your hand from body heat, but that doesn't come up in everyday conversation all that much), and 2.] lava.  And in the case of lava it's a bit of a misnomer because lava is liquid by definition.  When it cools and solidifies it's just igneous rock.  Either way, some serious heat is involved, not just what you can do in your kitchen.

Comment: @Astralbee "This is somewhat in complete contrast "  Shame on you!  If it's somewhat it isn't complete.  If it's complete it isn't somewhat. And an an English language forum too!

Comment: @LaurencePayne That error came about through multiple stages of editing, which all my answers generally go through just to please the pedants on here.

Comment: @Astralbee Be quick!  You have only a few minutes to correct 'all my answers generally...'  :-)

Comment: "Nobody would ever say 'molten ice'" Nice! I'm adding this to my list of Confusing Phrases to be Used Randomly.

Comment: @grault Well, quite. Molten ice would be boiling water. It's like calling bread 'raw toast'.

Answer (score 46):

*Molten* was formerly a past participle of *melt*: (the OED says "Middle English– **molten** (now *archaic*)".

In modern use it is only an adjective.

Comment: Compare "break" / "broken", "speak" / "spoken", or "smite" / "smitten".

Comment: And archaically, "help" / "holpen".

Comment: An archaic example that is still in use is "seethe" / "sodden".

Comment: For certain values of "in use". Like "molten", "sodden" has parted company with its verb, and exists only as an adjective, with a meaning not obviously related to "seethe".

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. The words are still in use, but their relationship is archaic.

Comment: I'll just note that "stricken" is gradually declining in use. I expect that by the end of this century it may be considered archaic (or at least obsolete), too.

Comment: An example of this archaic past-participle sense's appearing in the old-fashioned English of a fairly recent writer is found in J.R.R. Tolkien's description of his elves' use of [engagement rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engagement_ring): "[...] betrothal [...] could be revoked by a public return of the rings, the rings then being molten and not again used for a betrothal" (found in [this other Stack Exchange answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126637/have-elrond-and-galadriel-ever-spoken-to-each-other-in-person/126639#126639)).

Comment: @MJD Just like molten then? (Which is also perfectly well in use, just not as the past participle.)

Answer (score 7):

Normally, only viscous liquids with a very high melting-point are *molten*, especially when something that’s normally very solid gets so hot that it changes and becomes hazardous, like *molten rock*, *molten iron* or *molten glass*.  Discussions of nuclear accidents often talk about “the molten core.”  We never say **molten water*, **molten ice*, or even **molten butter*. (**Edit:** Michael Harvey found a news story from British Columbia that referred to “molten butter used as a weapon” in Canadian prisons.  I stand corrected, but I think this illustrates the point that something *molten* is dangerous.)

One important way that *molten* is like an adjective and *melted* is a past participle: something that melts and then cools and becomes solid again still is/has been *melted*, but is no longer *molten*.

The word is sometimes used in literary or poetic ways.  For example, English translations of the Bible call a bronze basin filled with water that once stood in a temple in Jerusalem “the Molten Sea” (translating a Hebrew term that means something like, “sea of cast metal”).

Comment: If there was a disaster in (say) a biscuit factory I can imagine an excitable reporter writing "Dozens of hapless workers perished as a tide of molten butter engulfed them when a tank ruptured'.

Comment: After making up that rather fanciful (I thought) example, I found this from a story about prison violence in British Columbia (Canada): "One of the most troubling attacks is the use of molten butter as a weapon to burn other inmates, said Dean Purdy, a spokesman for the union representing prison guards".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That is interesting. I had checked Google Ngrams and found “molten butter” at a low enough background level that most of the hits are false positives, but apparently people do sometimes say “molten butter” when it’s not supposed to be melted, and dangerous.

Comment: I kind of think molten is scary, (lava, tar, metal) whereas melted could be homely and nice (butter, cheese, chocolate).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Right. That’s an important part of the connotation that the other answers, good as they are, left out: something *molten* is dangerous because of its high temperature, but *melted* is a neutral scientific term.

Comment: Also, being molten is not an everyday state for the substance (rocks, metal and tar are not usually runny and liable to burn you) whereas butter and cheese are often seen in a safely runny state (ignoring badly run cookie factories, Canadian prisons, etc). I don't think native speakers would think of saying 'molten ice'.